# how to connect sql server 2008 on vmware with local machine sql server 2008 client

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection, vmware, sqlclient

I have windows7 professional edition machine. on which i settled up the VMware (windows server 2008) with the sql server 2008. Also I have set up the sql server 2008 client application. I want to access the sql server 2008 on vm database from the local machine sql server client machine. what should i need to do ? and what setting i need to configure?

Comment: hello guys , its bit urgent, can you guys help me out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should treat the virtual machine as a separate computer on your network. To access the database from your host machine you need to follow the same steps as you would when installing the server on one machine and the client on another (firewall, security configuration, choose protocols to allow, DNS or IP etc). I suggest you search for general instructions on how to install and configure SQL Server for use on a network.